# Deselect duplicates in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

Database ::

- id         subid
- 1           1
- 2           1
- 3           2
- 4           3

The id column is automatically incremented and primary
subid is any number.

I want to arrange subid in decreasing order, remove rows which consists
duplicate subid in it and get rows

Result i want ::

- id         subid
- 4           3
- 3           2
- 2           1

Comment: Is it important for you which record would remain: [1 1] or [1 2]?

Comment: not necessary , any record is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(id), subid FROM table GROUP BY subid ORDER BY subid DESC
```

Comment: It will only work by using an undefined bit of logic. With your test data for subid 1 it may bring back the id of 1 or 2. Which one it brings back is undefined and may change at any time.

Comment: yea but it is ok for me [1,1] or [1,2]

Comment: Fair enough, as long as you know the issue (which other solutions avoid), and that this would give an error in most flavours of SQL.

Comment: @Kickstart Could you explain me please what the problem is because I don't understand. A concrete example would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I will try. I will add this as an extra answer to try to give examples

Comment: @Kickstart (I can write comment only here) Thanks for the explanation of GROUP BY even if I know what that is about...but I have to tell the truth I didn't know this setting 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY' and sometimes I use the GROUP BY without specify the row from that group by using group functions....but not anymore.Thanks. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
select max(id), subid group by subid order by subid desc
```

Comment: Maybe you should add the ORDER BY clause for the answer to be perfect ;-)

Comment: @schlonzo true, true :D

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
order by (col) ASC or DESC
```

To have ascending or descending sorting

Use also

```
group by (col)
```

or

```
distinct
```

To drop out duplicate datas

Answer (score 1):

An explanation for @Geri of the use of GROUP BY.

with the accepted answer of :-

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY subid ORDER BY subid DESC
```

the query selects all columns grouped by subid. In this case there is just 1 other column (although in other queries there could be many other columns). GROUP BY is designed to work with aggregate functions, for example MAX. With MAX(id) MySQL will find all the rows for each subid and then find the maximum value of id for each subid and return that.

So for subid 2 there is only a single id of 3 so that is obviously the max value of the id for that subid and will be returned, similarly for subid of 3 the only id is 4. For subid of 1 the possible values of id are 1 and 2. As 2 is the highest value it will be returned.

Without an aggregate function MySQL is free to chose any value of id, and which one it choosing is not defined and may change.

So for subid of 1 it might return the id of 1 or the id of 2.

Most flavours of SQL will issue an error in the situation where there is a column in the SELECT clause which is not the result of an aggregate function and is also not mentioned in the GROUP BY clause. By default MySQL does not error in this situation, and there are logical reasons for this to be correct. For example with extra columns which are entirely dependent on a column that is in the GROUP BY clause - such as grouping by a unique user id and pulling back the users name, and this behaviour is defined in the SQL standards although exact implementation is patchy (and of course it becomes a non issue if these directly related columns are added to the GROUP BY clause).

MySQL can be set up to error in this situation, bringing it more in to line with other flavours of SQL by running with only_full_group_by set up:-

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

The answer by @franglais of:-

```
select max(id), subid group by subid order by subid desc
```

avoids the issue of which value of id to be returned being undefined, as it is specifying that for each subid returned the maximum id value for that subid will be returned.